# How to I attach a marker to the end of my circle progress bar SVG in React Native?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, animation, svg

So I have a semi-circle style progress bar, using SVG and two `<cirlce>` elements, one that moves along with `strokedashOffset`. I want to attach a marker end that moves with the circle progress section, as if it sits on the end but can't work out how to do that.

```
        <Svg
          viewBox="0 0 180 90"
          width="100%"
          height="180px">
          <Circle
            cx="90"
            cy="100%"
            r=55
            fill="none"
            stroke="purple"
            strokeOpacity={0.5}
            strokeWidth=24
          />
          <Circle
            animatedProps={animatedProps}
            cx="90"
            cy="100%"
            r=55
            fill="none"
            stroke="purple
            strokeWidth=24
            strokeDasharray={strokeDashArray} // calculated based on values.
          />
        </Svg>
```

I want it to look like:

[image: you can see the marker on the svg]

Answer (score 1):

You could set the dial as a rectangle and use css for the animation:

```css
.dial {
  animation: rotate 4s linear infinite;
  transform-origin: 90px 90px;
}


@keyframes rotate {
  
  0% {
    transform: rotate(-90deg)
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(90deg)
  }
}
```

```html
<Svg
          viewBox="0 0 180 90"
          width="100%"
          height="180px">
          <Circle
            cx="90"
            cy="90"
            r=55
            fill="none"
            stroke="purple"
            strokeOpacity="0.5"
            strokeWidth=24
          />

          <Path class="dial"
            d="M90,35 A 55,55 0 0 0 90 145" stroke="green" fill="none"
          />
          
            <rect class="dial" x="90" y="30" width="3" height="10" rx="1" stroke="purple" fill="white"/>
        </Svg>
```

Comment: I would've tried this but I failed to mention that I am using React Native, properties such as transform-origin don't exist